# Prevent ng build from checking index html

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I stumbled upon a problem when building the app using `ng build`. The app is fully functional if I set `index` in `angular-cli.json` to `index.html` but in my case I need `index` to be `base.jinja2 - Python Templating Engine` and it causes error while building.

The reason of those errors are just because `base.jinja2` has its own data bindings `undefined errors during build` and I just want to make `ng build` avoid error checking `base.jinja2` because there's no point doing it at least in my case.

Actually all I wanted is that `script` and `link` elements appending in `index` during `ng build`, If there's another way to do it I would highly appreciate it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you use the same interpolation character {{}} , you can change it on jinja side or angular